# How can new console windows be created for each run when running a console program from Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2017, console

I am looking for how to get the behavior of older versions of Visual Studio where each time a console application is started through the IDE via Debug->Start Witout Debugging or Ctrl+F5, a new console window is created and remains present after the program completes. The current version opens a console window the first time but then reuses it on subsequent runs after deleting the contents of the old run. In general, it is convenient not to have to close multiple windows manually, but I would like to visually compare outputs after various changes to the program. I had hoped that the debugging options would offer a way, but I did not see anything promising. Thanks for any information!

Comment: I don't experience such behaviour. Each run spawns a new Command Prompt.

Comment: Hi, could you please share the detail steps and sample code to reproduce this issue in VS 2017? I tried to follow the description, Start without debugging and popups a new console window, change code and start without debugging again, still popups a new console windows like this screenshot: https://1drv.ms/u/s!Atv5QNuFrncKmFKiRlHSxRhBCxU0 not sure I misunderstand your meaning or not.

Comment: The picture at https://1drv.ms/u/s!Atv5QNuFrncKmFKiRlHSxRhBCxU0 is exactly what I want and someone else is getting it by default. Visual Studio still will support separate consoles. I just need the option settings. I get the same behavior with Professional and Community editions.

Comment: Steps to show the issue are (1) Open Visual Studio 2017. (2) Select Menu->File->New->Project... to get the New Project dialog. (3) In the dialog on the left select Installed->Visual C++->Windows Desktop (4) In the middle select Windows Console Application. (5) Leave the default names for the project, location, and solution as they are, leave the checkbox for "Create directory for solution" checked and the checkbox for "Create new Git repository" unckecked (all defaults) and click OK. This creates the default console project and application.

Comment: (6) Press ctl-F5 to run outside of the debugger. (7) Click "Yes" button to the prompt to build the project. The program runs and prints Hello World and some information about the process and info on how to close the window. (8) Press ctl-F5 again in Visual Studio. The program runs again using the same console window, with all information the same, except for the process number.

Comment: One thing I noticed different in the image at https://1drv.ms/u/s!Atv5QNuFrncKmFKiRlHSxRhBCxU0 is that that application is in C# while mine is in C++. I have noticed before that the two do not always stay in synch regarding features. For example the brace alignment marks were in the C# editor before they came to C++. I just tried a default C# console application, and I do indeed get separate console windows. Now the question becomes whether it can still be done in C++.

Comment: I just installed VS 2022 Community and the reused, single-console behavior is what I get. Quite annoying and I've never seen it before.