# Visual Studio 2022 on Windows 11 reuses the same console window on successive runs, overwriting the previous output

Tags: visual-studio, console-application, windows-11

I have VS 2022 Community installed on Windows 10 on another machine and it does not have the same behavoir. As the title says, on Windows 11, when running a c++ project that uses `/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE`, with or without debugging (F8), successive runs do not open a new console window. Instead, they clear the existing one and use that to output stdio.

I can change this behavoir by adding `system("pause");` at the end of the program or any other user-input IO function that prevents exiting of main(), but I want to know what is causing this very anoying issue.

I've looked all through the VS options and project settings, as well as the Windows 11 Control Panel Terminal Settings, with no luck. This is happening on a brand-new computer and install of VS 2022. The issue happens with both project types under "Create a new project" > "Console App" or "Empty Project". It also happens if I create a Windows Desktop Application, replace everything in the source cpp file with `int main() {}`, and change `/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS` to `/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE`.

Comment: Recreating or clearing a console window is generally too fast to notice the difference. 
 Or to matter at all since the end result is the same.  The Win11 console is also a lot faster than the Win10 version.  Update the question to tell us how you can tell and why it matters.

Comment: Speed is totally irrelevant, and the end result is NOT the same. I need the console window to **remain open across multiple runs** to compare outputs, as has been the behavior for the last ~25 years. Previously, when you pressed 'F8', visual studio *creates a new console window* and runs the executable in that window, and has never reused the console window from a previous run, as it does now. Don't other people get this behavior? Please suggest how I modify the question to make this clear. How is it not obvious why it matters? Basic debugging involves comparing runs between code changes.

Comment: Hmm, the option to leave the console window open was [added in VS2019](https://www.cyotek.com/blog/new-option-in-visual-studio-2019-keeps-console-window-open-after-debugging).  Hard to guess what you've been doing for 25 years.

Comment: That option is totally irrelevant to my question, which you still don't understand, and I don't know how to explain it anymore clearly. Regardless of how you run the program (debugging or without debugging), I need the console window to NOT be **overwritten** across runs. **I need a new console window to be created for each run,** so I can compare outputs and code changes.

Comment: Possible duplicate question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54657838/how-can-new-console-windows-be-created-for-each-run-when-running-a-console-progr

Comment: I got an answer from "someone" on the Microsoft forum, but it mentions an option that doesn't exist for me: Tools > Options > Debugging > General > "Reuse Console Window". https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1399661/visual-studio-2022-on-windows-11-reuses-the-same-c

Comment: Ugly hack: Load, build and run a project that has `system("pause");` as the last line in `main()` so the program doesn't end. Don't close the output window after running. Close current project and load the project you want to work on. Build/run that project and the output console will be in a separate window, as long as you keep the original program window open and running. Note that simply adding `system("pause");` to the working project and keeping a running window open will prevent compiling the EXE file, hence the reason for the first project. What a Microsoft Mess (TM).

Answer (score 0):

Even though this is a [known bug confirmed by Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1399661/visual-studio-2022-on-windows-11-reuses-the-same-c), I had to solve it myself. Here is a work-around that I hope is useful to others.

**Create an External Tool:**

1. Select: `Tools > External Tools > Add`
2. Title: `RunWithoutDebugging`
3. Command: `cmd.exe`
4. Arguments: `/c "$(TargetName) & pause"`  (Or,
   one can drop the `& pause` and deselect "Close on exit")
5. Initial directory: `$(TargetDir)`

**Create a shortcut key:**

1. Select: `Tools > Options > Environment > Keyboard`
2. Type `Tools.ExternalCommand` in Show commands containing:
3. Select `Tools.ExternalCommandX`, where X is the menu item number of the RunWithoutDebugging Tool.
4. Click `Press shortcut keys:` and use CTRL-F11 to make it act just like the built-in "RunWithoutDebug" command, or use another key combination of your choice.